# A local variable can't be used inside an inner class. So why does this code work?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a student studying for the Java 7 OCP exam, and he presented me with this problem. Both he and I understand that a local variable can't be used within the method's inner class unless it's final, but he presented me with the following code which runs just fine:

```
public class TestC195 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestC195 myObject = new TestC195();
        myObject.doStuff();
    }

    private String x = "Outer 2";

    void doStuff() {
        String z = "local";

        class myInner {
            public void seeOuter() {
                System.out.println("outer: " + x);
                System.out.println("outer: " + z);
            }
        }
        myInner in = new myInner();
        in.seeOuter();

    }

}
```

The output is:

```
outer: Outer 2
outer: local
```

So what are we both missing?

Comment: It's [class member](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: You're probably compiling with Java 8, where the rule slightly changes: the variable must only be "effectively" final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are compiling with java 8 it is because it is effectively final  [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517916/why-this-inner-class-code-compiles/41518287#41518287)